# What is the probability that the highest of the three numbers obtained from three dice will be exactly a $4$?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

> Question: You are going to toll three dice. What is the probability that the highest of the three numbers will be exactly a $4$?

My attempt:

The first die obtains number $4$ with probability $\frac{1}{6}.$
Then the remaining two dice can take numbers $1,2,3,4$ only. So each of them has probability $\frac{4}{6}.$
In total, the required probability is 
$$\frac{1}{6}\times \frac{4}{6} \times \frac{4}{6} \times 3 = \frac{2}{9}.$$
But apparently this is not the answer. 
It is $\frac{37}{216}.$

May I know where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: The first die does not need to be $4$

Comment: @DanielMathias: that's why Idonknow multiplied by $3$.

Comment: Your method over counts the cases in which you get more than one $4$.

Comment: Hint (for a solution):  For each $n$ compute the probability that the max is $≤n$.  Then subtract.

Answer (score 3):

You've summed the probabilities of the events that one particular die shows a $4$ and the other two show not more than $4$. Unfortunately, those events are not disjoint, so you've double-counted the cases where several $4$s appear. To fix that, it helps to separate your computations by the number of $4$s rolled:

The probability that exactly one $4$ is rolled, and the other dice show less, is $\frac 16 \times \frac 36 \times \frac 36 \times 3 = \frac{27}{216}$.

The probability that exactly two $4$s are rolled, and the third die shows less, is $\frac 16 \times \frac 16 \times \frac 36 \times 3 = \frac{9}{216}$.

The probability that all three dice show a $4$ is $\frac 16 \times \frac 16 \times \frac 16 = \frac{1}{216}$.

Together, this makes $\frac{37}{216}$.

Answer (score 3):

P(highest of the three numbers will be exactly a $4$)

=P(highest of the three numbers will be at most a $4$)-P(highest of the three numbers will be at most a $3$)

=${\Big(\frac46\Big)}^3-{\Big(\frac36\Big)}^3$

=$\frac{64}{216}-\frac{27}{216}$

=$\frac{37}{216}$